# Array of pointers to objects and inherited objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, inheritance

I am trying to  make a program which creates an array of pointers to objects, including inherited objects.
The error I'm getting is on the first bracket ( of the cSClass eg `SArray[2] = new cSClass(...);` (Last line at the bottom of all the code). The error says "no instance of constructor cSClass::cSClass matches the argument list"

Thank you

All the code is below:

The code for the header of the superclass is:

```
class sClass;

class sClass {
protected:
    std::string name;
    int yearBuilt;
public:
    // Constructor
    sClass(string n = "s1", int yb = 2000) {
        name = n;
        yearBuilt = yb;
    }
// Mutator functions
void setName(string);
void setYearBuilt(int);

// Accessor functions
string getName() {
    return name;
}
int getYearBuilt() {
    return yearBuilt;
}

// Functions
void getInfo();
};
```

main class of the superclass:

```
#include "sClass.h"
using namespace std;

// Mutators
void sClass::setName(string n) {
    name = n;
}
void sClass::setYearBuilt(int yb) {
    yearBuilt = yb;
}

// Print function
void sClass::getInfo() {
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Year Built: " << yearBuilt << endl;
}
```

Code for the subclass header:

```
#include "sClass.h"

class cSClass : public sClass {
protected:
    int maxPassengers;
public:
    // Constructor
    cSClass(int mp = 2000) : sClass() {
        maxPassengers = mp;
    }

    // Mutator functions
    void setMaxPassengers(int);

    // Accessor functions
    int getMaxPassengers() {
        return maxPassengers;
    }

    // Functions
    void getInfo() {
    }
};
```

Code for the subclass class:
    #include "cSClass.h"

```
// Mutators
void cSClass::setMaxPassengers(int mp) {
    maxPassengers = mp;
}

// Print function
void cSClass::getInfo() {
    cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Maximum  Passengers: " << maxPassengers << endl;
}
```

And lastly this is the main program code in which i am getting errors where i  am trying to fill the array:
    #include "sClass.h"
    #include "cSClass.h"

```
int main() {
sClass *SArray[6];

    SArray[0] = new sClass(...);
    SArray[1] = new sClass(...);
    SArray[2] = new cSClass(...);
    SArray[3] = new cSClass(...);
}
```

Edit: Error is at the top, and the arguments I'm passing are

```
SArray[2] = new cSClass("RMS Queen Mary 2", 2003, 2700);
```

Comment: What errors? Paste them into the question.

Comment: `new sClass(...)` - What are the actual arguments you are passing here?  This is important since the error is clearly complaining about the constructor arguments.

Comment: And are you literally typing `...` in your constructors? Or is it supposed to values? The biggest issue is that your superclass does NOT have a default constructor, but you try calling it anyway in your subclass constructor.

Comment: 1) Is this `Ship(string n = "s1", int yb = 2000) {...}` `sClass`'s constructor? (upd ok after post edition)  2) There is no 3-arguments `cSClass` constructor, only 1-argument: `cSClass(int mp = 2000) {...}`, pass two other arguments too.

Comment: Edit at the bottom of the post, also @TedLyngmo that was an error, Ship was supposed to be sClass too

Comment: @fas yep that was what was missing, such a silly mistake... Thank you!

Comment: You have 2 definitions of `cSClass::getInfo();` and your compiler _should_ complain about that. Which constructor is `cSClass("RMS Queen Mary 2", 2003, 2700)` supposed to match? Make a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The constructor needed for this to work is missing:

```
SArray[2] = new cSClass("RMS Queen Mary 2", 2003, 2700);
```

It could look like this

```
class cSClass : public sClass {
    cSClass(const std::string& name, int yb, int mp) :
        sClass(name, yb),
        maxPassengers{mp}
    {}
    //...
}
```

You also have some other problems:

- You have a non-`virtual` destructor in the base class. When you `delete` your objects through a non-`virtual` base class pointer, only the base class destructor will be called. To fix that, add this to `sClass`:

  ```
  virtual ~sClass() = default;
  ```
- Two definitions of `cSClass::getInfo()`. Settle for only declaring the function in the class definition and leave the definition of the member function in the `.cpp` file as-is.
- Memory leaks since you don't `delete` what you've `new`ed. To avoid that problem, it's better to use smart pointers that will `delete` the object when it goes out of scope, like it will in case an exception is thrown (that you `catch`). Example:

  ```
  #include <memory>
  //...
  std::unique_ptr<sClass> SArray[6]; // or std::array<std::unique_ptr<sClass>, 6> sArray;
  SArray[2] = std::make_unique<sClass>();
  SArray[2] = std::make_unique<cSClass>("RMS Queen Mary 2", 2003, 2700);
  ```

  Note: If you instead want a dynamic amount of `sClass` pointers, use a `std::vector`:

  ```
  #include <vector>
  //...
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sClass>> SArray;

  SArray.push_back(std::make_unique<sClass>());
  SArray.push_back(std::make_unique<sClass>());
  SArray.push_back(std::make_unique<cSClass>("RMS Queen Mary 2", 2003, 2700));
  SArray.push_back(std::make_unique<cSClass>("RMS Queen Mary 2", 2003, 2700));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There are two fundamental errors in your code!

First, you have provided *two* definitions for the `getInfo` member function of the `cSClass`. If you want to keep the second (out-of-body) definition, then you need to remove the *definition* part of the (in-body) declaration. So, replace:

```cpp
    // Functions
    void getInfo() { /// Note: adding the { } provides a function DEFINITION
    }
```

with this:

```cpp
    // Functions
    void getInfo(); // No body provided, so it's JUST a declaration (defined elsewhere)
```

Then, the calls you make to your constructors cannot have the `...` in the argument list (though I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with this). Simply provide *empty* argument lists:

```cpp
    SArray[0] = new sClass();
    SArray[1] = new sClass();
    SArray[2] = new cSClass();
    SArray[3] = new cSClass();
```

or, as there is no argument, you can invoke the 'default' constructor by omitting the argument lists completely:

```cpp
    SArray[0] = new sClass;
    SArray[1] = new sClass;
    SArray[2] = new cSClass;
    SArray[3] = new cSClass;
```

Also, for completeness, remember to free the memory for the objects you created with `new`, when you're done with them:

```cpp
    delete SArray[0];
    delete SArray[1];
    delete SArray[2];
    delete SArray[3];
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.